# Customize What I see at Login

Tags: preferences

I am a volunteer at a non-profit.  The organization does lots of stuff with Civi, but I do only one very specific thing.  Each time I log on, I spend a couple minutes setting p my screen to do that thing...Components>Advanced Search>>Search Panel>>>Search Parameters, Keywords, etc.

Is there a way to set Preferences so that each time I log in I am automatically taken to the screen I want to see to begin my search?

Much obliged!
Phil

Comment: Welcome Phil!  It sounds like your menus don't quite match the standard CiviCRM menus.  Are you able to edit your question to post a screenshot?  Also, could you include your CiviCRM version (it's at the bottom of each CiviCRM page) and your CMS if you know it (WordPress, Drupal, etc.)?  Thanks!

Comment: also if you can describe the sort of search you are doing it may help

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I made a video of what I am doing.  I hope this is viewable. 
 It shows the screen I enter and navigate to before I begin to input the search criteria.<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c2ao1xdkEuLB9VCxaxkMmE_IC_49ufYc/preview" width="640" height="480"></iframe>